# How does a for-each loop work?

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop, foreach

How does a for-each loop works when it calls a method, either recursively or a different method?

Example:

```
for(String permutation : permute(remaining))
    {   

      // Concatenate the first character with the permutations of the remaining chars
      set.add(chars.charAt(i) + permutation);
    }
```

By the way the method  **permute**  takes in a String and returns a set.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you code it and step though it in a debugger, like Eclipse?

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion, as posed.

Comment: or use javap to disassemble!

Comment: +1 for actually trying to understand what strongly appears to be your homework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for the `enhanced for` statement, the expression:

```
for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement
```

Is executed as follows:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

Thus, the `Expression` (which must be of type `Iterable`) only has its `iterator()` method called once.

Comment: @ user1965283 : Welcome to SO. Please accept the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Calls it once, stores the result, does foreach.

Like this:

```
Collection<String> temp = permute(remaining);
for(String permutation : temp) {
...
}
```

Edit: If this is recursive, it really makes no difference. Every layer of recursion simply has its own scope, and thus its own "temp" variable. Thus the permute function will recurse to the lowest level, then each higher level will do its *completely separate* `foreach` loop successively.

Comment: @user1965283 No problem, but don't forget to accept your preferred answer (Which should be ulmangt's, as his answer is cooler than mine)

Answer (score 2):

If we compile this Test

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (String s : set) {
        }
    }
}
```

and decompile Test.class with JAD we will see that javac replaced for-each with this code

```
    Set set = new HashSet();
    String s;
    for(Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        s = (String)iterator.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach loop works on any class that implements the `Iterable` interface, and is only syntax sugar for calling `hasNext()` and `next()` on an `Iterator`. Same thread same loop and the function is called once.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the result of `permute(remaining)` is evaluated *before* one enters into the loop.  While the enhanced for loop is really nothing more than syntactic sugar for iterators, it still follows the same principles as other loops would - it has to have a set to operate with before it can do anything else.

A simpler example would be something like this:

```
while(input.hasNext())
```

That's something you may see in projects that read in an indefinite amount of lines.  The expression `input.hasNext()` has to be evaluated first, then you may loop.